# MYSQL contar un valor de una tabla a otra para actualizar un campo

Tags: mysql

agradecería de sus valiosa ayuda, actualmente ando desarrollando un sistema el cual me ah dado ciertas complicaciones, ahorita quisiera que me ayudaran en saber como contar cuantas palabras de estado='VENCIDO' hay por cada contrato para actualizar un campo de otra tabla.

Actualmente tengo dos tablas una llamada usuariosservicio en el cual el campo a recibir el valor y actualizar es recibosVencidos y la otra tabla que se llama carritorecibos donde tengo un campo llamado estado el cual se actualiza cuando se cumple cierta fecha y cambia a VENCIDO.

Anteriormente requería sumar unos valores de unos campos a otro mas o menos similar a lo que quiero ahora y lo hacia de esta manera:

```
update usuariosservicio c 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT contrato, sum(vR) AS total 
    from carritorecibos
    GROUP BY contrato
) x ON c.contrato = x.contrato
SET c.recibosVencidos=x.total
```

Pensé que con tan solo cambiar el sum por COUNT y otorgarle el campo a evaluar mas el =VENCIDO seria suficiente, pero no... me quedo así, solo que me da un dato erróneo: total 49 que son los 49 registros que tiene cada contrato.

```
update usuariosservicio c 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT contrato, COUNT(estado='VENCIDO') AS total 
    from carritorecibos
    GROUP BY contrato
) x ON c.contrato = x.contrato
SET c.recibosVencidos=x.total
```

**¿Cómo puedo hacer para que me cuente solo lo VENCIDO dentro del campo estado?**

De antemano doy gracias a David J P. por su valiosa ayuda, dios bendiga tu dia desde siempre, edito mi pregunta para exponer de igual forma la manera en que un amigo y gran hermano del alma me ayudo a resolver este detalle, de echo, comparto para que tenga alguien mas otra referencia de como realizar este proceso, el código es el siguiente:

```
UPDATE usuariosservicio a INNER JOIN ( SELECT contrato, COUNT(CASE estado WHEN 'VENCIDO' THEN 1 ELSE null END) AS TOTAL_VENCIDO FROM carritorecibos a  GROUP BY contrato ORDER BY contrato) tabla2 ON a.contrato = tabla2.contrato SET a.recibosVencidos = tabla2.TOTAL_VENCIDO;
```

**¡Espero que esto le sirva a alguien mas, saludos a todos y bendiciones!**

Comment: No pongas la condición dentro del `COUNT`, sino en un `WHERE` :)

Comment: Lo que pasa que necesito que se cuente los vencidos existentes por cada contrato y a cada contrato le actualice en el campo recibosVencidos la cantidad de vencidos que tiene, así como me lo planteas creo solo sacaría el total de vencidos que hay pero completo no por contrato, ¿me podrías ayudar? que esto me trae de cabeza.

Comment: Claro, modifica la pregunta añadiendo la estructura de la tabla con unos datos de ejemplo (phpmyadmin->exportar) y qué resultado esperas para esos datos de muestra. Seguro que se ve mucho mejor con un ejemplo que tratando de entender las explicaciones :)

Comment: @DavidJP entonces como seria la solución porque me interesa la verdad

Comment: @JavierG.Raya Ok, hubiera sido mejor esperar a que la pregunta quedara bien formulada pero, ya que te interesa, aclaro el comentario en la respuesta

Comment: vale muchas gracias @DavidJP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que planteo es esto:

```
update usuariosservicio c 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT contrato, COUNT(*) AS total 
    from carritorecibos
    WHERE estado='VENCIDO'
    GROUP BY contrato
) x ON c.contrato = x.contrato
SET c.recibosVencidos=x.total;
```

Y sí que actualizará el número de recibos **por contrato** gracias al `GROUP BY`.

Tu sistema también funcionaría sustituyendo `COUNT` por `SUM`:

```
update usuariosservicio c 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT contrato, SUM(estado='VENCIDO') AS total 
    from carritorecibos
    GROUP BY contrato
) x ON c.contrato = x.contrato
SET c.recibosVencidos=x.total;
```

Aunque mejor meter la comparación en un `IF`, por la coherencia de tipos de datos. Un `TRUE` vale `1`, pero igual el lenguaje se pone exigente en futuras versiones.

```
update usuariosservicio c 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT contrato, SUM(if(estado='VENCIDO',1,0)) AS total 
    from carritorecibos
    GROUP BY contrato
) x ON c.contrato = x.contrato
SET c.recibosVencidos=x.total;
```

Dejo las tablas con unos datos de ejemplo para reproducir el caso:

```
CREATE TABLE carritorecibos(
  contrato int,
  vR float,
  estado varchar(15)
  );
CREATE TABLE usuariosservicio(
  contrato int,
  recibosVencidos int
  );

INSERT INTO carritorecibos (contrato, estado) VALUES
  (1,'VENCIDO'),(1,'PAGADO'),
  (1,'VENCIDO'),(1,'PAGADO'),
  (2,'VENCIDO'),(3,'PAGADO'),
  (4,'VENCIDO'),(4,'PAGADO');
INSERT INTO usuariosservicio
  SELECT DISTINCT contrato,0 FROM carritorecibos;
```

Obteniendo:

```
+----------+-----------------+
| contrato | recibosVencidos |
+----------+-----------------+
|        1 |               2 |
|        2 |               1 |
|        3 |               0 |
|        4 |               1 |
+----------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu colaboración mi amigo, aunque lo resolví diferente, al rato edito para que alguien mas igual pueda salir de algún problema parecido.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda hasta hoy pude publicar la forma en que me ayudaron, igual tu código es muy bueno, saludos!